# Vertex shader fails to compile, but no message from Info Log

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to set up a simple vertex shader. When I compile it, it fails (according to GL_COMPILE_STATUS), but the info log is empty, leaving me nothing to work with from a debugging standpoint.

Here is my code:

```
GLuint vertexShader, fragmentShader;

char *code =

"void main(void)\
{\
    vec4 a = gl_Vertex;\
    a.x = a.x * 0.5;\
    a.y = a.y * 0.5;\
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * a;\
}";


int length = strlen(code);

vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
//fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &code, &length);

glCompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

GLint compiled;
GLint logLength;

glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);

glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH , &logLength);
if (logLength > 1)
{
    GLchar* compiler_log = (GLchar*)malloc(logLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, logLength, 0, compiler_log);
    printf("%s\n", compiler_log);
    free (compiler_log);
}
```

I'm aware that this is pretty messy, and since I'm new to shaders I'm sure there's something wrong with my shader code. However, the thing that is bugging the hell out of me is the lack of debugging information. The code above results in `compiled` being `GL_FALSE` (meaning the code failed to compile) and `logLength` being 0 (meaning the info log is empty). What gives?  Isn't that the whole point of the info log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glCompileShader` take a shader number returned from `glCreateShader` not a shader type.

In this case

```
glCompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
```

should be

```
glCompileShader(vertexShader);
```

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. I guess since `GLenum` is basically a `GLuint` it didn't give me an error. It also explains why there was no error log on `vertexShader`, because I hadn't even tried to compile it yet! I'm gonna take a break for a while.